# Unable to play .m3u8 file with flutter package better player

Tags: flutter, mobile, video-player

I have a .m3u8 file that contains information about a video but I am unable to play it using the BetterPlayer Flutter package.
This is my sample code

```dart
var dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
    BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
    "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B0391873-25D4-471A-AB13-05D5FF8701F9/Documents/content.publicId/test.m3u8",
    subtitles: null,
    headers: {"cookie":"COOKIE_FOR_AWS_CLOUDFRONT_ACCESS"},
    liveStream: true
  );
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
GetDataFromUrl failed: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FE19C886-73B8-49C0-A770-6BAEAD354947/Documents/content.publicId/test.m3u8

Failed to load video: Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12865
"(null)" [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: The operation
couldn’t be completed. (CoreMediaErrorDomain error -12865.), null,
null)
```

These are the contents of the .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:37
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128, URI="https://PATH_TO_ENCRYPTION_KEY",IV=0x413873f3924c752d99c7083c0c99931c
#EXTINF:36.440000, https://example.com/test_480p_0000.ts
#EXTINF:28.040000, https://example.com/test_480p_0001.ts
#EXTINF:28.360000, https://example.com/test_480p_0002.ts
#EXTINF:29.920000, https://example.com/test_480p_0003.ts
#EXTINF:36.920000, https://example.com/test_480p_0004.ts
#EXTINF:21.040000, https://example.com/test_480p_0005.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```